# Prevent invalid user input in SuggestBox?

Tags: java, gwt

I have `SuggestBox` taking user input and displaying `suggestions` in a popup using GWT.

```
SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(myData, new TextArea());
```

How can I prevent the user to put characters in the `TextArea` for which no suggestions exist?

I think the `SuggestBox` examines the text that has been put into the `TextArea`, and then displays the suggestions. But how could I prevent characters that do no match anymore?

Comment: Why would you block the user from typing and finding out there is no match to his input?

Comment: `SuggestBox`, as its names suggests, is about _suggesting_ things; it's not a _combo box_. It can possibly be made to work that way but, believe me, there are so many traps it's easier to start from scratch, or use something like [GWT Chosen](http://jdramaix.github.com/gwtchosen/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need that

```
   TextArea area = new TextArea();
             area.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                    if(event.getNativeKeyCode()==13 ||....){//Add remaining key codes which you dont want.For example i added enter key which keycode is 13.Remove that and add your key codes there. 
                        event.preventDefault();
                 }  
                }
            });
```

And then

```
SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(myData,area);
```

Comment: This is a good general approach, anyway I only want to prevent certain keys/characters if NO suggestions are available. Thus I cannot just prevent a keycode in general, as I of course do not want to prevent any characters on start. Only characters that are to match the suggestions. So that the suggestion dropdown is shown, but not hidden because the user simply cannot enter any invalid chars. But I'm missing any ideas of how to achieve that...

Comment: I don't know how much expensive it is..put all your first letter of suggested items in a list and then check when user typing.if the letter not found in the list return otherwise suggest..